# Using My Own Callback with an HttpRequest Object

Tags: javascript, callback, httprequest

I'm writing an Http Request without the use of a library (another script was having conflits...)

But Im having trouble with the scope of my object. Below is the calling script, then the Ajax_Request object follows.

```
function loadCard(e) {
var element = e.target;
if($('overlay')) {
    return false; //something is already over the layout
}

var card    =   '/card/'+element.id;
var option  = {method:'post', parameters:'test', async:true}

loadOverlay();
var ajax = new Ajax_Request(card, option);
```

}

//Ajax_Request

```
function Ajax_Request(url, options) {

if(typeof url !== 'undefined') {
    this.url = url;
}

if(typeof options.method !== 'undefined') {
    this.method = options.method;
} else {
    this.method = 'get';
}

if(typeof options.parameters !== 'undefined') {
    this.parameters = options.parameters;
}

if(typeof options.async !== 'undefined') {
    this.async = true;
} else {
    this.async = false;
}

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} //check for MS browser

this.makeRequest = function() {
    try {
        this.request.onreadystatechange = this.checkReadyState;
        this.request.open(this.method, this.url, this.async);
        if(this.method == 'post') {
            this.request.send(this.parameters);
        } else {
            this.request.send(null);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}

this.setResponse = function(r) {
    alert(r)
    this.response = r;
}

this.getResponse = function() {
    return this.responseText;
}


this.checkReadyState = function(r) {
    switch(this.readyState) {
        case 4:
        //Represents a "loaded" state in which the response has been completely received.
        if(this.status == 200) {
            this.setResponse(this.responseText)
        }

        ...

    }

  }
}
```

I'm trying to set the response to a property so my calling object can work with it.
But when I try to call this.setResponse(), I get an error that it's undefined. 
How can I tie the onreadystatechange callback to my program properly?

The script otherwise returns the data properly, and I could simply output it right there, but I need a bit more flexibility.

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to you because inside the `checkReadyState` function `this` actually represents the XMLHttPRequest instance not you Ajax_Request object, thus `this.setResponse` is undefined. In order to reference your object´s method you have to use a little trick: `var that = this`.

```
function Ajax_Request(url, options) {
    var that = this;

    ...

    this.checkReadyState = function (r) {
        switch(this.readyState) {
            case 4:
            if(this.status == 200) {
                    // "this" refers to the XMLHttpRequest, 
                    // but "that" refers your custom  Ajax object
                    that.setResponse(this.responseText)
            }

        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes complete sense, however - if I change this.setResponse() to Ajax_Request.setResponse() 
I still get Ajax_Rquest.setResponse() - it still generates an error of undefined or is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the problem, but you shouldn't be referring to `Ajax_Request` within the constructor. Use `this` instead. (`this` refers to the actual object instance—`Ajax_Request` refers to the object constructor.)

```
this.makeRequest = function() {
        try {
                this.request.onreadystatechange = this.checkReadyState;
                this.request.open(this.method, this.url, this.async);
                if(this.method == 'post') {
                        this.request.send(this.parameters);
                } else {
                        this.request.send(null);
                }
        } catch(err) {
                alert(err);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this.checkReadyState, try changing `this.setResponse(this.responseText)` to `this.setResponse(this.request.responseText);`.

Comment: This doesn't work, for the same reason I'm losing connection with my object. this.request is undefined in the checkReadyState callback function.